# Suppress Field List sidebar

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a process that creates a form, which is then used in a subform control.

I have suppressed the visual creation, via `docmd.echo` but the sidebar Field List shows and then recedes.

Is there a way to suppress the Field List sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

This is will apply when you re-open the database. There are a half dozen ways around that the user can use with MS Accesss 2010. These can be changed manually from the Options menu.

```
Sub SetStartUp()
    SetProp "StartupShowDBWindow", True, dbBoolean
    SetProp "AllowFullMenus", True, dbBoolean
End Sub

Sub SetProp(PropName As String, PropVal As Variant, Optional PropType = dbText)
Dim db As Object
Dim prp As Object
Dim strTitle As String

Const PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND As Integer = 3270

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   Set db = CurrentDb

   ' Try to set the property. If it fails, the property does not exist.
   db.Properties(PropName) = PropVal

ExitLine:
   db.Close
   Set db = Nothing
   Set prp = Nothing
   Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   If Err.Number = PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND Then
      ' Create the new property.
      Set prp = db.CreateProperty(PropName, PropType, PropVal)
      db.Properties.Append prp
      Resume Next
   Else
      Resume ExitLine
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the end-user(s) will have run-time Access, will this still work?

Comment: What do you mean by work? It will hide the navigation pane, yes. There are more options you may wish to consider.

Comment: i know the runtime is minimized form of professional version of office.  As such, certain capabilities are not present or available.  I just want to make sure there are not any other factors i need to consider.

Comment: It has just occurred to me that I may have misunderstood you. Do you mean the left-hand pane that lists tables?

Comment: no, when you create a new form, a sidebar (RHS) opens up (for me) where i can dummy-add fields from tables and such.  Is there a way of suppressing that sidebar (or whatever its technical term is)?

Comment: Ah! you should not get that with a compiled version on a runtime. you can test by using the runtime switch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15475/discussion-between-goldbishop-and-remou)